# Pegar Ip e HostName dos visitantes que preenche formulário de contato

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Boa tarde, senhores. Tenho uma aplicação web em asp.net mvc + angularjs que possuí um formulário de contato. Gostaria de saber qual o ip do usuário e hostname dele que está preenchendo essa informação, consigo fazer isso em javascrip ou asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar algo como:

```
var ip =  Request.UserHostAddress;

var hostName = Request.UserHostName;
```

Lembrando que o `Request` você consegue obter diversos valores, como **Cookies**, **UserAgent**, dentre muitos outros dados.